# Auto updates via aptitude?

Tags: 11.04, update-manager

Just like here: [How do I set my system to auto-update without user interaction?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47937/how-do-i-set-my-system-to-auto-update-without-user-interaction/47939)

How can I set the auto-updates via aptitude? 
Are there any auto-update features in aptitude?

Comment: what do you actually want? a script witch perform update, upgrade command after a certain time or day !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unattended-upgrades` package will automatically apply security updates on a scheduled basis.  The `apticron` package will check for available package updates daily, and tell you about it.

Both may be configured to have more agressive update behaviours.  Neither will use aptitude by default: for that, your best strategy would be to create your own cronjob (perhaps based on one of these packages, or the other question referenced) which calls aptitude with the appropriate arguments on the schedule you prefer, and provides notification of success or failure by the method you prefer.